# Problema con for y array sencillo,

Tags: c++, array

El programa me pide leer 5 valores de un arreglo de enteros por teclado (Números diferentes).  y calcular cuál es la distancia en casillas que les separa del número mayor, imprimiendo el número mayor y la distancia que los separa de este.

Me atore tratando de encontrar el numero mayor  , no se si exista una manera de guardar una posiciòn de un vector sin alterar su contenido porque en el ejemplo vector[n]=big creo que me cambia el valor del vector.
Y bueno en general no pude resolver la mitad del problema de todos modos les dejo lo que intente y el feedback se aprecia.

```
{
    int vector[5];
    int n;
    //ENTRADA DE DATOS
    cout << " Ingrese 5 valores (separados por enter) " << endl;
        for (n = 0; n < 5; n++)
        {
        cin >> vector[n];
        }
    
    int big=vector[0];
    
    //PROCESO

    for (n=0;n<5; n++)
    {
      if (vector[n]>= big )
      {
       vector[n]=big;
      }
    }
  //SALIDA PARA VER SI EL VALOR SE ALTERO
    for (n = 0; n < 5; n++)
        {
       cout << vector[n] <<endl;
        }
```

Es mi primer post aqui asi que disculpas de antemano si esta confusa mi pregunta o algo asi.

Answer (score 1):

¡Bienvenido Nyanko!

Se entiende bien lo que quieres hacer, el método es el correcto pero tienes dos pequeños problemas:

1. Utilizas un contador `n` para llevar la cuenta pero nunca la reinicias, es decir que cuando entras a tu segundo bucle `for` el valor de `n` irá: 5,6,7,8... Te recomiendo que hagas el contador cero antes de cada iteración o que declares la variable dentro del for, así: `for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++)`.
2. Cuando encuentras un número mayor que `big` lo que quieres hacer es guardar el valor del vector en esa variable. Y no al revés.

Tomando esto en cuenta, tu código se vería así:

```
int vector[5];
//ENTRADA DE DATOS
cout << " Ingrese 5 valores (separados por enter) " << endl;
for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
  cin >> vector[n];
}

int big = vector[0];

//PROCESO

for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
  if (vector[n] >= big) {
    big = vector[n];
  }
}

cout<<endl<<"Array luego del proceso:"<<endl;

//SALIDA PARA VER SI EL VALOR SE ALTERO
for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
  cout << vector[n]<< " ";
}

cout<<endl<<endl<<"Numero mas grande:"<<big<<endl;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabia que  esas cosas eran el problema y considerando eso pude resolver el problema

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza la función [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) de la cabecera de algoritmos ([`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)). Esta función devuelve un iterador del que podrás obtener la distancia a otro iterador usando [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) (de la cabecera [`<iterator>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator)):

```
int numeros[5] = { 1, 3, 5, 2, 4 };
auto mayor = std::max_element(std::begin(numeros), std::end(numeros));

for (int indice = 0; indice != 5; ++indice)
    std::cout << "El numero " << numeros[indice]
        << " esta distanciado del maximo " << std::distance(&numeros[indice], mayor)
        << " posiciones\n";
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/NTsMwEITP9lMsQUKJaiSg5NKkvfEUUCFjL2El/0S2IxVVffbgNGkRXCzPaPbbWdX398pI143jLTllBo3Qko8poLQ7/utJ0/lA6euPSQmDTD7sOCeXwEpyZcWPnE3KDRaDj6/1HrZwhEcBawG1gCcBz3BqOJND8nnm24cciElvNlYe3tGgRZfKs/GBXUYupErMKXT6alUN5@wzE8ppJTlNCjPtobn8b7ZQN7BazbLijJ0Zyg8J2haKF7MUhWLSl9JzfJ/jbEoBxiRBU36dIqk9aDS5@4HsMnimLgEs7/5xxHxndeX1PpIi7zC@uWK6IWAagsvF@WkcfwA)</kbd>.

Comment: Gracias, muy interesantes y utiles esas funciones